# Generate Regression Equation in R with existing Dummy Variables

Tags: r, regression, dummy-variable

I'm working to generate the following regression.
`Charges = Bo + B1 * Age + B2 * BMI + B3 * Children + B4 * Female + B5 * Smoker + B6 *` `Wintersprings + B7 * WinterPark + B8 * Oviedo`
In regards to the Cities (Winter Springs etc..) these are dummy variables with the default being Sanford which isn't in the data set so I believe it would be items with "0"

would this be the correct way to write the regression?

```
Chargeslm <- lm(Charges ~ age + bmi +children + female + smoker + wintersprings + winterpark + oviedo, data = insurace) 
summary(Chargeslm)
```

Comment: looks ok to me.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong thanks! I then created a data.frame for prediction..
`data.frame <- insurance newprediction <- data.frame(age=35, BMI=26,Children=1, Female=1, Smoker=0, WinterSprings=0, WinterPark=0, Oviedo=0)
Predict(chargeslm, newdata = new prediction, interval="confidence", level=.95`

Does this formula look correct?

Comment: almost, you want `predict(Chargeslm, newdata=newprediction, interval="confidence", level=.95)` note the lower-case "p" on `predict` and the upper-case "C" on `Chargeslm`.